# Multiple aggregations for the same data

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have two queries:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(warehouseCode) as count,
    warehouseCode
  FROM 'sparePartEventsTable'
  WHERE 
    sparePartCode = 'SP.0000' AND 
    sparePartConsumed = 'true' 
  GROUP BY warehouseCode
  ORDER BY count DESC
```

and

```
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as eventsCount,
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(epochSeconds)) as day
  FROM 'sparePartEventsTable'
  WHERE 
    sparePartCode = 'SP.0000' AND 
    sparePartConsumed = 'true' 
  GROUP BY day
  ORDER BY day
```

As you can see the underlying data is the same, but I'm returning two different aggregations. Is there a way in SQL to avoid hitting the disk twice?

How would you implement this is either BigQuery or Postgres?

In mongodb I would build a cursor on the underlying common data, and then write an aggregation pipeline that spits two results.

EDIT: It seems that `UNION ALL` could be a first solution, but at least in postgres it scans twice. Sergey in the comment suggested `GROUPING SETS`, but unfortunately they are not available in BigQuery. An answer in either Postgres or BigQuery dialect will be accepted, extra points if both solutions are posted :)

Comment: I'm actually running it both on Postgres and BigQuery

Comment: I guess, you can take look on GROUPING SETS, CUBE operations, if they are supported by your database

Comment: Thank you @Sergey I think you pointed me in the right direction https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-grouping-sets/

Comment: Do you want to combine the 2 resultsets? If yes, then how?

Comment: @forpas Ideally I would like to return two different results. Consider I'm very noob at SQL, my main goal is to avoid querying (or scanning) a huge table twice. I added how would I do it in Mongo.

Comment: @forpas are you sure it's not better to put both DB tags? In postgres I think I can use grouping sets, which are not in bigQuery. I would honestly be interested in hearing both solutions.

Comment: It is better to edit your question and set the 2 tags again and explicitly mention that you are interested for solutions in both dialects.

Comment: If you want to return two different results then you're going to have to scan something twice. You could write the minimal data necessary to satisfy both queries into a temp table and then query that twice - but whether that would perform "better" than just querying the main table only you can know - by trial and error. If you can combine both requirements into a single resultset then you could use a CTE to query the minimal data necessary to satisfy both queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below (BigQuery) option

```
with temp as (
  select 
    warehouseCode, 
    count(*) over(partition by warehouseCode) as `count`,
    date(timestamp_seconds(epochSeconds)) as day,
    count(*) over(partition by unix_date(date(timestamp_seconds(epochSeconds)))) as eventsCount
  from `sparePartEventsTable`
  where sparePartCode = 'SP.0000' 
  and sparePartConsumed = 'true' 
)
select distinct 'warehouseCode' type, '' || warehouseCode as value, `count` from temp union all
select distinct 'day', string(day), eventsCount from temp
```

with output like below

[image]

Comment: Amazing answer, made me want to apply to the job positions you are advertising :) One question: how is it possible that they are magically ordered?

Comment: I think it is just because very small dummy set. In real case you will need to add explicit ‘order by …’

Comment: You have all my admiration.